# issue with grouping (Teradata SQL)

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm getting the error "Selected non aggregate values must be part of the associated group"

I started getting this error when I added the line " ,current_date - pmnt_rlse_dt as "Days Since Paid"

I know it has something to do with the group by but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

```
    select ee.alias_last_nm || ', ' || ee.alias_first_nm as "Custodian"
   ,clm.i_sys_clm
   ,clm.c_clm as "Claim Number"
   ,clm.i_pol as "Policy Number"
   ,clm.n_lst as "Last Name"
   ,clm.n_fst as "First Name"
   ,clm.c_sta_clm as "Status"
   ,mx_dt as "Last Payment Date"

from ltc_p.vltc_clm_mo clm

left join (select indiv_sorce_syst_cd
            ,sorce_upc_indiv_id
            ,alias_last_nm
            ,alias_first_nm
from edw_p.upc_indiv_alias_v2
where row_end_dt = '9999-12-31' and
indiv_sorce_syst_cd = 'ORG') ee
on clm.c_ams_clm = ee.sorce_upc_indiv_id

inner join(select sorce_claim_id
            ,max(pmnt_rlse_dt) as mx_dt
            ,current_date - pmnt_rlse_dt as "Days Since Paid"
from ltc_p.claim_pmnt pp

having  max(pmnt_rlse_dt) is not null) as d
on clm.i_sys_clm = d.sorce_claim_id

where clm.c_sta_clm = 'AC'
order by 1,2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is related to using the `MAX` function in your derived table query `d` without using a GROUP BY clause.

However, I'm guessing that the purpose is to return the max pmnt_rlse_dt for each sorce_id.  If so, please try this which uses an OLAP window function:

```
inner join(
   select  sorce_claim_id
         , pmnt_rlse_dt   as mx_dt
         , current_date - pmnt_rlse_dt as "Days Since Paid" 
   from    ltc_p.claim_pmnt
   where   pmnt_rlse_dt is not null
   qualify row_number() over (partition by sorce_claim_id
                              order by pmnt_rlse_dt desc) = 1
   ) as d
```

The `QUALIFY` expression takes a little while to fully understand, but it is very powerful.

Comment: Excellent, that worked and did not throw any errors. However I think i meant to have it in the initial select statement... my idea was to create a new column showing the date difference in days between the current date and the pmnt_rlse_dt.

Comment: Got it -  ,dys as "Days since paid" added to the first select statement. Thanks so much Bob, you're the man.

Answer (score 0):

you dont ahve a group by clause.

You can only use aggragation functions like max and having when you are grouping data

Comment: I added a group by 1 at the end but it made no difference. The query was working fine before i added the line ",current_date - pmnt_rlse_dt as "Days Since Paid""